# Can't launch my c++ projet because of Info.plist missing

Tags: c++, xcode

I have a project with Xcode in C++, 
But now I have to use Camera, 
the problem is that Xcode has no generate Info.plist project.
How can I solve that ?

Comment: When you are in Xcode you click on projects name, then on build settings  then go to packaging group and in there should be Info.plist. You say it isn't there? What there is? How did you make that project that lacks Info.plist?

Comment: There is some information about info.plist like the link but it is not set. I have answer with a picture of this.

Comment: You should edit your question to put all relevant information into it.